# Add one child item to many parent items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I have `owners` that have many `notes`. I want to efficiently add the same new `note` to many owners as individual records so I can alter it for each `owner` later without affecting the other `owners`.

The `owners` I need to add the `note` to are known only as a list of IDs at this point (selected from a multi select list).

Is there any way more efficient than the following?

```
owner_ids = [1,2,3,4]
note = Note.new(params[:note])
owner_ids.each do |owner_id|
  Owner.find(owner_id).notes << note
end
```

OR

```
owner_ids = [1,2,3,4]
owner_ids.each do |owner_id|
  Note.create(owner_id: owner_id, subject: params[:note][:subject], content: params[:note][:content])
end
```

Using Ruby 2 with Rails 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ActiveRecord transaction method, which will execute SQL in one transaction. This can save your some time

```
ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do 
  owner_ids.each do |owner_id|
    Note.create(owner_id: owner_id, subject: params[:note][:subject], content: params[:note][:content])
  end
end
```

Also take a look at [activerecord-import gem](https://github.com/zdennis/activerecord-import), maybe it will suit your needs better.

Comment: Thanks Mikhail, presumably the gem essentially does what your code suggests - wraps a transaction around the imports. I'll give it a go, or fall back to a transaction block. Ta!

Answer (score 1):

```
owner_ids = [1,2,3,4]
owner_ids.each do |owner_id|
  Note.create(params[:note].merge({owner_id: owner_id}))
end
```

UPD: wrap all creations in a transaction is a good idea too.

Comment: Thanks Alex, upvoted for the params merge suggestion but I think the import gem in Mikhails answer is the way I'll go.